# A non mouse-reacting layer (form)

Tags: forms, delphi, events, mouse

Is it possible to create a transparent form which does not react to mouse events?

And by that I mean that the mouse events are passed to the application beneath.

Or the question could maybe be:

How can I pass mouse events from my software, to the application underneath it?

Thank you.

Comment: SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, getWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT or WS_EX_LAYERED); WS_EX_LAYERED is the magic for this, and Handle is the Forms Handle

Comment: Thanks, but it's still preventing the mouse events to reach the application beneath the form.